# Reading WiFi properties from APs without getting connected

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I would like to know if there is any way in Android to read some configurable property from a WiFi access points without getting connected/authenticated to the network. Basically I would like to list only the networks that implements/advertises a specific web service I am working on.

Thanks,
- Rafael

Comment: please define "service".

Comment: That means, a web service I am working on.

Comment: 4.5 years for a response. Tremendous!

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. This account was dormant but in respect to your question, I decided to edit this item clarifying its content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WifiManager`.

> This class provides the primary API for managing all aspects of Wi-Fi connectivity. Get an instance of this class by calling Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE). It deals with several categories of items:
>
> The list of configured networks. The list can be viewed and updated, and attributes of individual entries can be modified.
>       The currently active Wi-Fi network, if any. Connectivity can be established or torn down, and dynamic information about the state of the network can be queried.
>       Results of access point scans, containing enough information to make decisions about what access point to connect to.
>       It defines the names of various Intent actions that are broadcast upon any sort of change in Wi-Fi state.
>       This is the API to use when performing Wi-Fi specific operations. To perform operations that pertain to network connectivity at an abstract level, use ConnectivityManager.

This is the link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

Comment: That's what I had in my mind ;) using WifiManager class ... tks anyway.

But how about reading information from the network without getting connected. Suppose your network has a kind of service and you would like to ad it in some way.

I even don't know if it's possible ... maybe using some configurable property from the network or maybe using some configurable property of the access point.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) instance:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = ( WifiManager ) mContext.getSystemService ( mContext.WIFI_SERVICE ) ;
```

You can also get [NetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) object:

```
    ConnectivityManager connManager = ( ConnectivityManager ) context
            .getSystemService ( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE ) ;
    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo ( ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI ) ;
```